# View count different in main list and search result

Tags: bug

A question of mine is currently in the Top list (most recent) and has had 13 views. However, if I search for "mirror symmetry in partial sum plot", it is listed in the search result with 2 views. Is this an expected behavior, in the sense that a searched item's view count reflects how many times it was viewed via a search? Or... is it a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Math meta SE. I've noticed the various search lists are quite often out of date in various ways, e.g., they show a question even if it's just been deleted, the question is still open even if it was recently closed and, of course, the view count is off. This is basically due to caching being used, for performance reasons. There are various network Meta posts related to this issue, but the only pertinent ones I could find re: your situation, are this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80636) and, to a lesser extent, this other [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291590).

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: In computer language, stack exchange data is only _eventually_ consistent, not consistent at every instant.